# Creating Relational class objects

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have table named Products and Categories, one of Products table's row include data like that:

```
ProductId,ProductName,CategoryId
```

And Categories include

```
CategoryId,CategoryInfo
```

So I m getting rows with using `ExecudeReader()` using ado.net like

```
List<ProductEntity> lst = new List<ProductEntity>();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "select ProductId,ProductName,CategoryId from Products";
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    lst.Add(new ProductEntity()
                    {
                        ProductId = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString()),
                        ProductName= reader[1].ToString(),
                        CategoryId=int.Parse(reader[2].ToString())
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

But I want to get CategoryInfo from Categories table too without using another `ExecuteReader()`. Can I create one entity class for both Product and Category if yes How I do that? Or another best practice exist?

Comment: What value `cmdText` has when used as command text?

Comment: use joins if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT p.ProductId, p.ProductName, p.CategoryId, c.CategoryInfo
FROM Products p
JOIN Categories c ON c.CategoryId = p.CategoryId
```

And get `CategoryInfo` as a fourth element returned by query:

```
CategoryInfo= reader[3].ToString()
```

To make it clear - you have to have `CategoryInfo` property within `ProductEntity` class.